# Numpy array assignment by boolean indices array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a very large array, but I'll use a smaller one to explain.

Given source array X

```
X = [ [1,1,1,1],
      [2,2,2,2],
      [3,3,3,3]]
```

A target array with the same size Y

```
Y = [ [-1,-1,-1,-1],
      [-2,-2,-2,-2],
      [-3,-3,-3,-3]]
```

And an assigment array IDX:

```
IDX = [ [1,0,0,0],
        [0,0,1,0],
        [0,1,0,1]]
```

I want to assign Y to X by IDX - Only assign where IDX==1
In this case, something like:

```
X[IDX] = Y[IDX]
```

will result in:

```
X = [ [-1,1,1,1],
      [2,2,-2,2],
      [3,-3,3,-3]]
```

How can this be done efficiently (not a for-loop) in numpy/pandas?
Thx

Comment: `IDX = IDX.astype(bool)`, and then just do it.

Comment: `np.where(IDX==1, Y,X)` use `X` , `Y` , `IDX` as numpy.array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `IDX` is a NumPy array of Boolean type, **and `X` and `Y` are NumPy arrays** then your intuition works:

```
X = np.array(X)
Y = np.array(Y)
IDX = np.array(IDX).astype(bool)

X[IDX] = Y[IDX]
```

This changes `X` in place.

If you don't want to do all this type casting, or don't want to overwrite `X`, then [`np.where()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) does what you want in one go:

```
np.where(IDX==1, Y, X)
```